# Android Studio "The emulator process for AVD Pixel_4_API_30 was killed" on AMD Ryzen 5 3600

Tags: android, emulation, android-virtual-device, amd-processor

I have a problem with the Android-Studio-Emulator. I recently switch form a Intel- to a AMD-Processor. Since that im facing issues with running the Android-Emulator. First i reinstalled Android Studio. Following the Guidelines on Github (https://github.com/google/android-emulator-hypervisor-driver-for-amd-processors) i installed AMD Emulator Hypervisor Driver for AMD Processors [Image 2], enabled CPU-Virtualization in BIOS and disabled Hyper-V in the Windows-Settings[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BkOPH.png), but i still get the same "The emulator process for AVD Pixel_4_API_30 was killed." error message [Image 3] if i try to start the emulator it also doesn't work with a "armeabi-v7a" image. I also update Windows to the version 10.0.19042 Build 19042 but as expected nothing changed. I never faced a problem which was this hard to fix i also tried serveral fixes on Youtube and on other posts on this website - no success. Im out of ideas. I would really appreciate some help.

Deactivation of Hyper-V in Windows-Settings:
[image: Deactivation of Hyper-V in Windows-Settings]

Installation of AMD Emulator Hypervisor Driver for AMD Processors:
[image: Installation of AMD Emulator Hypervisor Driver for AMD Processors]

Error:
[image: Error]

Comment: I had to install [Radeon Graphics and Ryzen Chipset Drivers for Windows](https://www.amd.com/en/support) and you can see the enabled/disabled features [here](https://imgur.com/a/kLX0NKM). You can also check for more details of this issue by clicking on eventlog while launching the Emulator.

Comment: I installed the Ryzen Chipset Driver and tried it with Windows Hypervisor Plattform on and off, but it i didn't work. The eventlog is also almost empty https://imgur.com/a/hmBIMA1.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a solution! After completely reinstalling windows everything works fine!

Answer (score 0):

Settings > Android SDK > SDK Tools > Android Emulator Hypervisor Drive for AMD Processors (installer) > install